# Is the technology of deferreds still used, albeit hidden from public APIs?

Tags: promise, ecmascript-6

Deferreds are not exposed in the ES2015 Promise API - is the deferred concept still used internally?

Put another way: is the technology of deferreds still used, but best practise now dictates that deferreds are not exposed to userland code?

Can Promises be said to be the public API corresponding to the resolved value (with states `pending` and `settled`?), in some sense wrapping an inner deferred corresponding to the operation (with states `resolved`, `rejected`?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of deferred is not used in the specification. [The word "deferred"](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/) appears exactly 0 times in the specification text.

Therefore, "the technology of deferreds" is not used. Engines and libraries typically just put resolve and reject directly on the promise object itself and then pass that around. Since ECMAScript direct implementations can't expose more properties than they are requested - engines use private properties for that - in V8 those are private symbols.

You can see the word deferred used in engines - but not in the same sense as you're used to - in [this example from v8](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/js/promise.js#L397-L428) the following is used:

```
 var deferred = NewPromiseCapability(constructor);
```

But the deferred object is actually a promise capability object, you can't do `deferred.resolve` but rather with the internal API you'd do:

```
 switch (status) {
    case kPending:
      PromiseAttachCallbacks(this, deferred, onResolve, onReject);
      break;
    case kFulfilled:
      PromiseEnqueue(GET_PRIVATE(this, promiseResultSymbol),
                     onResolve, deferred, kFulfilled);
      break;
    case kRejected:
      if (!HAS_DEFINED_PRIVATE(this, promiseHasHandlerSymbol)) {
        // Promise has already been rejected, but had no handler.
        // Revoke previously triggered reject event.
        %PromiseRevokeReject(this);
      }
      PromiseEnqueue(GET_PRIVATE(this, promiseResultSymbol),
                     onReject, deferred, kRejected);
      break;
  }
```

That said, deferreds can still easily be created by wrapping the promise constructor which wraps synchronously:

```
function Defer() {
    this.promise = new Promise((res, rej) => {
        this.resolve = res;
        this.reject = rej;
    });
}

var d = new Defer();
d.resolve(); // and so on
```

The promise constructor has to allocate a closure and thus is slower - so engines typically never call it directly when implementing things like `then`.

Comment: Actually a promise capability as specced is pretty much a deferred, isn't it? It's basically a `{promise, resolve, reject}` record.